# Replace one button with another when countdown timer ends

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple countdown timer which is launched on the click of the `.btn-submit-a` button. I tried to make it so that after the timer ends, **button A** is replaced by **button B** (`.btn-submit-b`), but, unfortunately, nothing comes out. How can I achieve this? I will be glad for any help.

```js
jQuery(function($){
  $('.btn-submit-a').on('click', doCount);
});

function doCount() {
var timeleft = 5;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
  if(timeleft <= 0){
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Time is Up";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + "<span class='remain'>seconds remain</span>";
  }
  timeleft -= 1;
}, 1000);
};
```

```css
.btn-submit-b {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" class="btn-submit-a">Button A</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn-submit-b">Button B</button>

<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Comment: Try using `$('.btn-submit-b').show()`

Comment: @ShriHariL thank you, I tried, however, unfortunately, it didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a weird combination between jquery and native code. You can do that ofcourse but I would recommend to stick to either jQuery or native where possible. Therefore I changed some code to jQuery functions.

This said you can hide and show elements with the [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) jQuery functions as you can see in the example below.

If you want to toggle them instead you can use [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.btn-submit-a').on('click', doCount);
});

function doCount() {
  var timeleft = 5;
  var downloadTimer = setInterval(function() {
    if (timeleft <= 0) {
      clearInterval(downloadTimer);
      $("#countdown").html("Time is Up");
      $('.btn-submit-a').hide();
      $('.btn-submit-b').show();
    } else {
      $("#countdown").html(timeleft + "<span class='remain'>seconds remain</span>");
    }
    timeleft -= 1;
  }, 1000);
};
```

```css
.btn-submit-b {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" class="btn-submit-a">Button A</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn-submit-b">Button B</button>

<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
jQuery(function($){
  $('.btn-submit-a').on('click', doCount);
});

function doCount() {
var timeleft = 5;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
  if(timeleft <= 0){
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Time is Up";
    
    // Add these lines
    $(".btn-submit-a").hide();
    $(".btn-submit-b").show();
  } else {
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + "<span class='remain'>seconds remain</span>";
  }
  timeleft -= 1;
}, 1000);
};
```

```css
.btn-submit-b {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" class="btn-submit-a">Button A</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn-submit-b">Button B</button>

<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).